# Throw an exception in C# and catch in IronPython

Tags: .net, exception, ironpython

I've been looking for a solution and all I find are ways to 'throw in Python and catch in C#'. Does anyone know how to do it the other way around?

Ideally I'd like to have a C# method and wrap all my Python code in a try/except block. When the C# method throws, I'd like to have the Python `except` catch it.

My last attempt:

```cs
ScriptEngine pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
dynamic pyScope = pyEngine.CreateScope();

Action<string> fire = (s) => { throw new Exception(); };
pyScope.Fire = fire;

// ... Load the script...
compiled = source.Compile();
compiled.Execute(pyScope);
// ...

// Somewhere else from a function called by the py script itself 
void calledByPy()
{
    m_pyscope.Fire("s");
}
```

On the Python side, my script looks like:

```python
try:
    calledByPy()
except System.Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

I'd like to see that `print str(e)` line called.

Comment: Please share how you use python and c# with example code showing the exception being seen by phython

Comment: I've edited the question - twice ;)

Comment: You wouldnt, its already handled. you might be able to view the output and capture it from there.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Who's handling what? Anyway that was just an example to give a better idea of what I am trying to do. Paerhaps there are different ways to achieve this beheaviour. Thanks for your time

Comment: Python is handling it.

Comment: not sure about that. The debugger breaks at `throw new Exception();`

Comment: Apparantly the solution is not to throw in C#, just let it go and if some not handled excecption happens it'll be caught by python

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the trouble is in your Python. I can't quite speak to all the C#, since I am loading up C# assemblies in IronPython with `clr.AddReference` rather than running an interpreter with `ScriptEngine`.

This sort of thing works fine:

```
import clr
import System
clr.AddReference(project_path + '\\bin\\Debug')
from Namespace import CSharpThing

try:
    foo = CSharpThing.DoStuff()  # Multithreaded. Can throw an AggregateException.
except System.AggregateException as ae:
    # I want more information than "One or more exceptions occurred"
    for e in ae.InnerExceptions:
        print(e)
    raise  # Rethrow the original exception, so I get a stack trace to it.
```